# How to add docker support for an Angular 7 application using VS2017?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi, angular7

I created an Angular 7 application using VS2017 by following [this documentation](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-create-an-angular-6-app-with-visual-studio-2017/). The application is working fine in local machine, but I want to add docker support for this angular application, and also deploy it into either local docker or local kubernetes.

So, can anyone help on that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the book that you referenced. But in general the steps would be:
- Try to run your application locally from command line (I guess it can be started with `dotnet run`).
- Create a Dockerfile
- Use official docker images that already include dotnet framework as Base-Image (e.g.: `from microsoft/dotnet:runtime`)
- In your Dockerfile you can add as much as you want (install dependencies, run unit-tests, etc.), but to keep it simple the following should be enough:

Dockerfile:

```
from microsoft/dotnet:runtime
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

- To optimize for performance you can use multi-stage docker images and split your Dockerfile into build and runtime

*Note, that I didn't read your tutorial, but this is how I would start with preparing for docker*

To work with kubernetes you can simply push your docker image (`docker build -t <your-tag>`) to a docker-registry, which your kubernetes cluster has access to and create a k8s-deployment for that contains that image. Locally you don't need a docker-registry but can simply `kubectl run ...`

See:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/
- and https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/docker-cli-to-kubectl/

Comment: I know that is for normal .NetCore applications. but I want to add the dokcer support for Angular applications.